# barplot graph not displaying properly in sweave & knitr generated pdf

Tags: r, pdf, plot, knitr, sweave

I do not know if this is a bug in knitr? or am I doing anything wrong.

I wanted to generate a barplot from a matrix generated from this vector (1):

```
14.556962,  8.227848, 51.898734, 19.303797,  6.012658, 10.126582, 28.797468, 35.759494, 14.873418, 10.443038, 11.708861, 20.253165, 38.924051, 22.468354,  6.645570, 11.501597, 23.003195, 36.741214, 17.891374, 10.862620, 13.870968, 33.548387, 34.516129, 13.548387, 4.516129
```

This is the code for the barplot (it is a stacked barplot) summing to 100 %

```
<<label=figealb1,fig=TRUE,height=3.8,results=hide,echo=FALSE>>=
barplot(matrix(as.vector(as.numeric(enzymy$C.ALB[,1:5])),ncol=5))
@
```

This vector (1) generally is what is printed when i call the `enzymy$C.ALB[,1:5]`

Now when I generate the pdf using the above code i would get a stacked barplot without the first column (4 columns total) !!!!

But if I generate it with copy pasing the results of the `enzymy$C.ALB[,1:5]` variable like this:

```
<<label=figealb,fig=TRUE,height=3.8,results=hide,echo=FALSE>>=
barplot(matrix(c(14.556962,  8.227848, 51.898734, 19.303797,  6.012658, 10.126582, 28.797468, 35.759494, 14.873418, 10.443038, 11.708861, 20.253165, 38.924051, 22.468354,  6.645570, 11.501597, 23.003195, 36.741214, 17.891374, 10.862620, 13.870968, 33.548387, 34.516129, 13.548387, 4.516129),ncol=5))
@
```

...then the plot is generated as it should - with five columns.

What could to be the problem?

`enzymy` is a list of data frames.

```
str(enzymy)
List of 14
 $ C.ALB  : num [1:5, 1:19] 14.56 8.23 51.9 19.3 6.01 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:19] "E1" "E2" "E3" "E4" ...
```

Exporting to an image or pdf through Rstudio works fine so it is only kniter/Swaeve problem.

Here is the image of a knitr/sweave pdf-generated plot

[image: corrupted plot]

Could anyone help?! Thanks

I am trying to make it REPRODUCIBLE as requested, so here it is:
1. I am using pdflatex,
RStudio Version 0.98.490,

```
> R.Version()
$platform
"x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$version.string
"R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)"

$nickname
"Sock it to Me"
```

You can download the database here: (please edit the path in the code below)

https://github.com/wolass/R/blob/master/colonies.csv

now load it and prepare:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE} 

<<>>=
colonies <- read.csv("path/colonies.csv",colClasses="character")
colonies <- colonies[,-3]
colonies <- colonies[,-5]
col_names <- c(1:3,5:35)
colonies[,col_names] <- lapply(colonies[,col_names] , factor)
colonies$Wiek.1 <- as.numeric(colonies$Wiek.1)


enzymy <- lapply(split(colonies, colonies$Wynik), function(x){
          foo<- lapply(lapply(lapply(x[,17:35],summary),function(x){x[2:6]}),prop.table)
          mat <- matrix(unlist(foo)*100,byrow=F,nrow=5)
          colnames(mat) <- c("E1","E2","E3","E4","E5","E6","E7","E8","E9","E10","E11","E12","E13","E14","E15","E16","E17","E18","E19")
  return(mat)
})
@

This graph is what it supposed to look like:

<<label=figealb,fig=TRUE,height=3.8,results=hide,echo=FALSE>>=
barplot(matrix(c(14.556962,  8.227848, 51.898734, 19.303797,  6.012658, 10.126582, 28.797468, 35.759494, 14.873418, 10.443038, 11.708861, 20.253165, 38.924051, 22.468354,  6.645570, 11.501597, 23.003195, 36.741214, 17.891374, 10.862620, 13.870968, 33.548387, 34.516129, 13.548387, 4.516129),ncol=5))
@

This is how it looks like unfortunately:

<<label=figealb1,fig=TRUE,height=3.8,results=hide,echo=FALSE>>=
barplot(matrix(as.vector(as.numeric(enzymy$C.ALB[,1:5])),ncol=5))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: doesn't `as.numeric(enzymy$C.ALB[,1:5])` give you an error

Comment: Make your problem reproducible, please.

Comment: Updated to make it reproducible.

Comment: the first column of `enzymy$C.ALB` is all `NA`, so it is plotting exactly what you tell it. You want `barplot(matrix(as.vector(as.numeric(enzymy$C.ALB[,2:6])),ncol=5))
`. Looking at the data at each step would save yourself a lot of headache

Comment: I am sorry but You are wrong. If you put this example that i provided into R: after you call `enzymy$C.ALB` you will get a 19 column vector. of which none columns are NA. And I did take the first column NA into account in the function `enzymy`. Here I got rid of the first NA column you reffer to: `foo<- lapply(lapply(lapply(x[,17:35],summary),function(x){x[2:6]}),prop.table)`